# How can I sign an android apk using Intellij?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I´m trying to make a signed apk using Intellij.

I can run normally this->.../build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk

But I´m trying to make a signed app to publish into Play Store.

According this [Generating a Signed Release APK Through an Artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-a-signed-apk-through-an-artifact.html) 
  It´s possible to Intellij generate a signed apk to publish....but I can´t.

Sometimes it´s not possible to install the apk at the phone...other times it´s possible to install, but it´s not working.

I didn´t understand about the resources of the artifact. What is necessary to make an artifact to generate a correct apk?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The place for Android questions is [android.se].

Comment: ok....thanks...moving my question!!!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! @GabrielaGarcia are you sure this question on topic on the Android StackExchange? This looks like it is about trying to build/deploy an app; which seems more like it would be on-topic at StackOverflow, or possibly here.